# How do you link two servers under the same IP adress, but under different ports?

Tags: networking, ip

Say I have Server 1 and Server 2, both are in charge of running a variety different services (Web-services, file hosting, etc.). Both servers servers are linked together by a D-Link DAP 1522, which serves as a gateway to the rest of the network, controlled by a Linksys WGA600N. I am planning on allowing outside access to these servers as well.

How would you set up the network, so that you can access either server on the same IP, but so that the port number determines which server is accessed, since each service has a different port number?

Comment: Configure the router. Duh.

Comment: This is obviously possible; even the cheapest home router will do this. What are you really trying to ask?

Comment: I would do this with LVS - but this seems to be too complicated. Why can you not assign different IPs to the servers? Or are you searching for a possibilty to forward an IP/Port to another IP/Port with that Cisco-Router?

Comment: @Nils Yep. That, and I want to keep it as simple as possible for everyone else. I know I can just assign two IP addresses, but no one wants to learn 2 IP addresses. They all expect a magic IP address that just works, both inside and outside of the network.

Comment: That is the reason, why there is DNS. Are you talking about web-services here, or is this a different game?

Comment: Web-services and others. (File Storage, MySQL, Autodesk Vault)

Comment: Strictly this is not routing any more, since you are above layer3 here. But propably possible with nowadays Ciscos. IMHO you would need a NATing firewall here, but I am not a firewall or network admin. I hope these comments help to clarify your question though. IMO you should provide the exact Cisco router name and firmware version of that router, though. This will help the networking guys here to determine wether what you want is possible with that hardware.

Comment: What you are after is hairpin NAT with port translation, I think.

Comment: Static NAT would be the way to go

Comment: @ILikePizza555 Anything that is left in the comments, should be in the original question. Many people skip comments, or never see them at all, depending on how they read the site. For other ideas on what to add to your question, see [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for that link, I'll read over it before I post another question on here. Is the information provided right now currently sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Set up port forwarding on your router.  Use the external IP address of your router as the 'shared' IP.
 I do this at home to access my IP cameras. I can use the Same IP and port on my client regardless of if I am at home or away. The same idea works here, you just set up the ports you want on your router to nat to the correct destination. Depending on the application, setting up a proxy is probably overkill here.

Comment: It sounds like the poster may be double nat'd. With one router between the internet and the router he is actually connected to (with these servers). If that is the case, the internet router must forward ports to the server router ip address and the server router must forward appropriate ports to on the appropriate server. -question sounds like a common setup on consumer grade hardware with a user that is unfamiliar with subnetting and network address translation.